# How can a function have multiple return values in Julia (vs. MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, function, julia

In MATLAB, the following code returns `m` and `s`:

```
function [m,s] = stat(x)
n = length(x);
m = sum(x)/n;
s = sqrt(sum((x-m).^2/n));
end
```

If I run the commands

```
values = [12.7, 45.4, 98.9, 26.6, 53.1];
[ave,stdev] = stat(values)
```

I get the following results:

```
ave = 47.3400
stdev = 29.4124
```

How would I define my `stat` function in Julia?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How would I define my `stat` function in Julia?

```
function stat(x)
  n = length(x)
  m = sum(x)/n
  s = sqrt(sum((x-m).^2/n))
  return m, s
end
```

For more details, see the section entitled [Multiple Return Values](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/index.html#Multiple-Return-Values-1) in the Julia documentation:

> In Julia, one returns a tuple of values to simulate returning multiple values. [...]

Comment: Yes, it works! I tried to get the values of `m` and `s` using this code: x = [1,2,3] and (av, sd) = stat(x), but I wonder what if `x` was an `m by n` matrix, how can someone get the results for each column `n` that is populated by `m` entries?

Comment: Julia's indexing notation uses square brackets (not parens, as in MATLAB). So, if `x` is a `2x2 Array`, `x[i,j]` is the entry on the `i`-th row, `j`-th column (assuming `i` and `j` are valid indices).